# What to enter in URL, login when you want to use terminal after installing devtools terminal?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

[image]I want to use terminal in browser but it is asking me to enter URL, login and password. I am not sure about this what to enter, I am trying to learn to develop RallyApps

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do. Did you find the getting started guide in the AppSDK help docs? https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/guide/getting_started

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do. Did you find the getting started guide in the AppSDK help docs?

https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/guide/getting_started

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the [Terminal Extensions](http://blog.dfilimonov.com/2013/09/12/devtools-terminal.html) documentation. You need to run your own terminal server to connect to a CLI from.